# Estimate the number of of operations required to perform the computations

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I have an equality:

> ∑<sub>1 to n</sub> j^2 = n · (n+1) · (2n+1)/6

Question wants me to estimate the number operations required to perform computations on the right and left side of equality.

For left side, I found:

> O(n · log^2 (n))

But for right side I do not know how to start...

Comment: Ask yourself, do you care about constants when evaluating Big-O?

Answer (score 1):

Since n is given, doing the calculation `(n+1)*(2n+1)/6` is done in constant time i.e. O(1)

Answer (score 1):

The left side is O (n) if you assume that calculating j^2 is a constant time operation. If not (if n can be really really large) then it it O (n log n log log n) if you use clever methods for calculating j^2, or O (n log n) if you use that j^2 = (j - 1)^2 + 2j + 1.

The right side is six operations if I'm counting right, which makes it O (1). Or O (log n log log n) if you take really large n, for example a million digits.